# how do I stop an event listener when a button dispensed is pressed in the following

Tags: angular, typescript

so how do I stop this event from being called once a button "dispensed" is pressed in another module, here's the code

```
 stopDrugOrder(e: Event, drugOrder: any, drugName: string) {
    const confirmDialog = this.dialog.open(SharedConfirmationComponent, {
      width: "25%",
      data: {
        modalTitle: `Stop Medicaton`,
        modalMessage: `You are about to stop ${drugName} for this patient, Click confirm to finish!`,
        showRemarksInput: true,
      },
      disableClose: false,
      panelClass: "custom-dialog-container",
    });

    confirmDialog.afterClosed().subscribe((confirmationObject) => {
      if (confirmationObject?.confirmed) {
        this.encounterService
          .voidEncounterWithReason({
            ...drugOrder?.encounter,
            voidReason: confirmationObject?.remarks || "",
          })
          .subscribe((response) => {
            if (!response?.error) {
              this.loadVisit.emit(this.visit);
            }
            if (response?.error) {
              this.errors = [...this.errors, response?.error];
            }
          });
      }
```

I have no idea here, kindly help

Answer (score 0):

Saying:

`e.target` refers to the element that triggered the event.

`e.currentTarget` which refers to the element that the event listener is attached to.

You can do the following:

```
stopDrugOrder(e: Event, drugOrder: any, drugName: string) {
    if(e.currentTarget is to be stopped){
      e.stopPropagation()
      return
    }
    //--- actual function ---
}
```